# how to keep make image responsive with fixed height in zurb foundation

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I want to keep the height of the image at 300px and auto hide image on left & right size while resizing the image in such a way that center of image is always visible.
[image]
**Example**
[image]

```
<div class="large-12 columns">
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f8/Auckland_airport_international_terminal.jpg/1024px-Auckland_airport_international_terminal.jpg"/><p></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

My approach to this would be to use the image as a background image. This will enable you to center it and crop it on resize, whilst still maintaining the 300px height that is required.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/NSS2T/4/

```
div {
    height: 300px;
    max-width: 100%;
    background: url('myImage.jpg') center center;
}
```

**Edited**

As you are using programmatically generated images, you will need to add calculated styling via jQuery as apposed to the CSS example i have given above.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/NSS2T/3/

```
HTML

<div>
    <img src="http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Guardian/Pix/pictures/2014/3/10/1394464252285/5a3508c4-7dd0-4bac-90ed-f13c11b53cef-460x276.jpeg" class="upload" />
</div>

CSS 
// this will offset the image by 50%

img {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
}

jQuery 
// this will loop through all images with a class of .upload and then apply a calculated margin offest to center the image

var imgWidth;

$('img.upload').each(function() {
    imgWidth = $(this).width() / 2;
    $(this).css('margin-left', '-'+imgWidth+'px');
});
```

Comment: This is fine but i have to assign source of image from  programmatically, is their a way we can do it with my HTML code using CSS.